# when i make save in (admin/settings) i got (local.ERROR: Undefined index: utubelink) error

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

when I make save in (admin/settings) I got (local.ERROR: Undefined index: utubelink) error
it is just in (admin/settings) other admin pages work fine.
I can not make any changes like changing the logo or name of the site.

laravel.log

```
[2022-01-08 15:46:38] local.ERROR: Undefined index: utubelink {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Undefined index: utubelink at /home/u0462672/new.maxtella.net/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/Settings.php:44)
```

Settings.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Model\Setting;
use Storage;
class Settings extends Controller {
    public function setting() {
        return view('admin.settings.settings', ['title' => trans('admin.settings')]);
}

public function setting_save() {
    $date=$this->validate(request(), [
        'logo'=>v_image(),
        ],[],
        [
            'logo'=>trans('admin.logo'),
            'icon'=>trans('admin.icon')
        ]);
    $data = request()->except(['_token', '_method']);

    if(request()->hasFile('logo')) {
        $file = request()->file('logo');
        $name = str_random(21) . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $size = $file->getSize();
        $mim = $file->getMimeType();
        $realpath = $file->getRealPath();
        $file->move(public_path('upload/settings/'), $name);
        $data['logo'] =  $name;

    }
    if(request()->hasFile('imgindex')) {
        $file = request()->file('imgindex');
        $name = str_random(21) . time() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $ext = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $size = $file->getSize();
        $mim = $file->getMimeType();
        $realpath = $file->getRealPath();
        $file->move(public_path('upload/settings/'), $name);
        $data['imgindex'] =  $name;
    }

    $data['utubelink'] = $data['utubelink'] != '' ? str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $data['utubelink']) : '';

    Setting::orderBy('id', 'desc')->update($data);
    session()->flash('success', trans('admin.updated_record'));
    return redirect(aurl('settings'));
}
}
```

how can fix it plz ?

Comment: try with clear the cache.

Comment: @SachinKumar i cleared mini time , did not work :(

Comment: there is no input named that in the request ... and you can't be running Laravel 5 and Laravel 8 at the same time

Answer (score 0):

Ok man Here is the issue.
The error log clear points that line number 44 has an issue. You are trying to access utubelink from $data array which does not exist.

```
$data['utubelink'] = $data['utubelink'] != '' ? str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $data['utubelink']) : '';
```

Replace with

```
$data['utubelink'] = ($data['utubelink'] ?? null) ? str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $data['utubelink']) : '';
```

I hope you are using PHP 7.0 or above. Read more about the [Null Coalescing Operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.coalesce) in PHP or just use `isset()`.

Comment: I replace it but did not work, but when I removed the line the error is gone!

Comment: check my latest answer. and don't remove the line otherwise your str will never replaced

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent these type of errors using `optional` Laravel helper method.

```
$data['utubelink'] = ! blank(optional($data)['utubelink']) ? str_replace("watch?v=", "embed/", $data['utubelink']) : '';
```

Read more: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

Comment: still not working :( i will read the doc thank you